# Can you make a PHP function recursive without repeating its name?

Tags: php, recursion

It's always bugged me a recursive function needs to name itself, when a instantiated class can use `$this` and a static method can use `self` etc.

Is there a similar way to do this in a recursive function without naming it again (just to cut down on maintenance)?

Obviously I could use `call_user_func` or the `__FUNCTION__` constant but I would prefer something less ugly.

Comment: Why is `__FUNCTION__` ugly? Seems to be a very good way to achieve what you want...

Comment: @Felix because it will probably need to be added to `call_user_func` or with `eval`. I'd prefer something like `self::($var)`

Comment: See my answer... You can use variable functions to avoid this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of [**variable functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and declare a variable with the function name at the beginning of you function (or wherever). No need for `call_user_func`:

```
function test($i) {
   $__name = __FUNCTION__;
   if($i > 5) {
       echo $i. "\n";
       $__name($i-1);
   }
}
```

Don't forget that using the *real* function name is probably more readable for other people :)
(at least provide a comment *why* you do this)

---

**Update**:
As @Alix mentions in his comment, it might be useful to declare `$__name` as [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static). This way, the value is not assigned over and over again to the variable.

Comment: Forgot about those. That does look a bit nicer than `call_user_func_array()`. Thanks +1

Comment: I agree with your last point. However I feel you *should* be able to rename a function without breaking recursive calls. Although I do realise changing function names breaks any call to it elsewhere. I guess this is why you should pick really good function names from the beginning!

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it looks cleaner to me. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @alex: It makes sense to make `$__name` static: `static $self = __FUNCTION__;`.

Comment: Is `__FUNCTION__` set at interpretation time or run time? Hmm.. I'm sensing a new question coming on here.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why this is ugly:

```
return call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
```

Versus:

```
return call_user_func_array('someFunction', func_get_args());
```

You would still need to use `call_user_func_array()` if you're looking to cut down on maintenance (if your functions have [a lot / a different number] of arguments).

Other than that [I don't see another way](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php). Also *a static method cannot reference itself using `self::`*, only to its class. You would also need to use the magic `__METHOD__` constant to do that.

Comment: Regarding `self::`, that's what I meant. You can access other methods in that same class with it. I just thought it looks ugly compared to something simple like `self`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function anyfunc() {
    __FUNCTION__();
}
```

if used in class:

```
protected function anymethod() {
    $this->{__FUNCTION__}();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to do this within a static method:

```
forward_static_call(array('self', __METHOD__), $arg1, $arg2, $etc);
```

This way if the method is renamed you dont have to worry about changing all the recursion calls within it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function self(){
  return call_user_func_array(debug_backtrace()[1]['function'], func_get_args());
}

function test($i) {
    if($i) {
        echo "$i<br>\n";
        self($i-1);
    }
}
test(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the arguments by combining `func_get_args()` and the `Variadic` or `...` added in 5.6.

As a procedural function

```
function foo($arg,$arg1) {
    __FUNCTION__(...func_get_args());
}
```

As a class method:

```
protected function foo($arg,$arg1,$arg3, $etc) {
    $this->{__FUNCTION__}(...func_get_args());
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Coincidently this works anytime you want to inject an array of arguments into a method or function...

For example (these are also equivalent)

```
public function foo($arg,$arg1)
   call_user_func_array([$this, __FUNCTION__], func_get_args());
}
```

`call_user_func_array` should be Deprecated in my opinion, because there is no need for it in several ways.  Most obvious to me is this.

```
public function foo($arg,$arg1)
   call_user_func([$this, __FUNCTION__], ...func_get_args());
}
```

The `...` is quite useful (I think it plays well with named arguments, though I haven't tried that yet).